# Select every nth term including first from sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-contentresolver

I am trying to select the first row and every fifth one after that (this gives me 4 queries with unique rows) but I am not sure that it is correct as my results are not as expected.

```
    //create the nth row selection
    int n = level + 5;

    //query the content resolver
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
            MainContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_ENGLISH,
            DatabaseOpenHelper.PROJECTION_ENGLISH,
            DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ROW_ID + " = " + (level+1) + " OR " + DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ROW_ID +" % " + n +" = 0",
            null,
            DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ROW_ID + " ASC"
    );
```

where `level` is in `[0,3]` interval.
The results do not add up to the expected value, and are twice as less (approximately).

---

How should my query method look like to select every fifth row starting from the first one?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using query like (I'm not sure about it's performance though):

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name,
  (SELECT count(*) - 1 FROM my_table t_inner WHERE t.id >= t_inner.id) AS ordinal 
FROM my_table t
WHERE ordinal % 5 == 0
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Or you can create `CursorWrapper` which will return subset of rows. The downside of the this approach is that you'll have to fetch every row from the database, which might be slow if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that the row IDs are consecutive,) `rowid % X = 0` selects every `X`th row, so you must not change `X`.

If you cannot change that term, you have to change another.
Either apply an offset to the `rowid` values (`(rowid - offset) % X = 0`), or compare against another value (`rowid % X = offset`), where `offset` is in the range from `0` to `X-1`.

Please note that the first comparison (`rowid = level+1`) is not necessary.